# How to create a resource timeline like view, but for dayGridView?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-4

I'm trying to build a view similar to the picture below. I have tried resourceDayGrid view, but this one places the resources as columns instead of rows. I have also tried the resourceTimelineDay, resourceTimelineWeek and resourceTimelineMonth and setting slotDuration: "24:00:00", but this doesn't do it for me since the slots that aren't 24 hours don't take fullwidth of the cell.

Example:

```
views:{
  resourceTimelineMonth:{
    duration: { days:7 },
    slotDuration:'24:00:00'
  },
  resourceTimelineWeek:{
    duration: { days:7 },
    slotDuration:'24:00:00'
  },
  resourceTimelineDay:{
    duration: { days:7 },
    slotDuration:'24:00:00'
  }
},
```

https://codepen.io/tuancaraballo/pen/poJrwLy?editable=true&editors=001

Do you have any suggestions? I would appreciate if you can point me in the right direction.

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It makes no sense to declare "resourceTimelineMonth" and then set its duration to 7 days. The same for "resourceTimelineDay". Its duration is defined already by its name. Equally you don't need to bother setting the duration of a resuorceTimelineWeek to 7 days - it already is!

And to make events stretch the whole width, you should define the `slotDuration` in days instead of hours.

So you can simplify your view definitions to this:

```
views:{
    resourceTimelineWeek: {
      slotDuration: { days: 1 }
    }
},
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/LYVjLMB

Comment: I have been stuck on this for a week. You are a life savior. Thank you for coming on my rescue here; I can't thank you enough. Cheers.